# What's new in TL2015

Tags: texlive

Since TL2015 was released (I'm installing it from the `iso` just now) I wonder if there are some big difference in the PDF output compared with TL2014.

I mean, can we produce two PDFs from the same code source with very visual difference?

For example, some fonts glyphs were improved or some rules for alignments, etc...

I'm not thinking about new versions of some packages (except if these new versions only work within TL2015) because the packages are another story.

Comment: Did you look at http://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#news?

Comment: @JosephWright, thanks. I hadn't find that. But I'm asking if somebody has a trick example showing really some difference to encourage people to upgrade to TL2015.

Comment: You miss my point :-) There are not a lot of engine-level changes on that list (there is a new LuaTeX version and `\Ucharcat` primitive in XeTeX). As such, I'm not sure you are going to find some killer feature, nor really should you as TeX is meant to be pretty stable!

Comment: for changes in latex 2015 you can see latex news 22 `texdoc ltnews`

Comment: Ow, I never heard about `ltnews`. Thanks.

Comment: Surely very different PDFs from the same source would indicate something very wrong in 2015? If we are taking packages out of it, at least. In any case, I don't think people should be encouraged to upgrade at this point, to be honest. (Not to say people should not upgrade: I just have, though I wouldn't have done so if it meant losing 2014.)